# Trouble using datagrid (or datagridview) in wpf or winform

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, datagrid

I have a datagrid with small database (sql compact)
Table contains more than 500 lines and each block contain different sections numbers;

The Xamle code :

```
  <Window x:Class="WpfApplication9.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="440" Width="690" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
<Grid>
    <Button Content="To TextBox" Height="29" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="561,272,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button1_Click" />
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" Height="234" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,0" Name="dataGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="644" />
    <CheckBox Content="Section Rate" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="126,313,0,0" Name="checkBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <CheckBox Content="Section Result" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="28,313,0,0" Name="checkBox2" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <CheckBox Content="Discipline" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="28,272,0,0" Name="checkBox3" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <TextBox Height="54" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="240,324,0,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="396" />
    <CheckBox Content="Total Biology" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="113,272,0,0" Name="checkBox4" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <CheckBox Content="Math" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="28,351,0,0" Name="checkBox5" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <CheckBox Content="Physics" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="113,351,0,0" Name="checkBox6" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
</Grid>
```

The Code behinde :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataRowView _data = dataGrid1.CurrentCell.Item as DataRowView;
        if (_data != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(_data.Row[0].ToString());
        }
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=C:\MyDatabase1.sdf");
        con.Open();
        SqlCeDataAdapter da = new SqlCeDataAdapter("select * from StudentGroup", con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(dt);
        dataGrid1.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
        //dataGrid1.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
        con.Close();
    }
```

I want to export the data to textbox1 based on selected checkbox, in this format :
line 1 : Group Number , GroupName , Discipline( or Total Biology : Sum of results of rows in Biology Column)
for each section number in selected Group Number : 
next lines : (Section Rate or Section Result , Math or Physics  ) ==>  based on selected checkbox

for example :

line 1 : 1,GPA,100(or 137= Total Biology)
and if SectionResultcheckbox and mathchechbox is both checked :
next lines will be :80 , 80, 90 ,70 ,54 ,31

I have tried this :

```
    DataRowView _data = dataGrid1.CurrentCell.Item as DataRowView;
        if (_data != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(_data.Row[0].ToString());
        }
```

but it does not work.

I do not know how to handle this issue ?
thanks for any help.

Comment: what is the question? what is not working? what is your trouble? Medicine can't be given without knowing the illness :)

Comment: @ No One : i have explained : I want to export the data to textbox1 based on selected checkbox, in this format : line 1 : Group Number , GroupName , Discipline( or Total Biology : Sum of results of rows in Biology Column)  and for each section number in selected Group Number : next lines : (Section Rate or Section Result , Math or Physics ) ==> based on selected checkbox

Comment: @SmartMan what happens when the `Discipline` checkbox is checked?...what should be the output??

Comment: @Kyle : if  Discipline checkbox is checked then the line 1 in textbox1 will be  : Group Number , GroupName , Discipline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if Grid SelectionUnit is set to "FullRow" then use below code.

```
((DataRowView)dgGroup.SelectedItem).Row -> This will give you current data row

((DataRowView)dgGroup.SelectedItem).Row.ItemArray[0] -> This will give first column value

((DataRowView)dgGroup.SelectedItem).Row.ItemArray[1] -> This will give second column value
```

if Grid SelectionUnit is set to "Cell" then use below code.

```
(DataRowView)dgGroup.SelectedCells[0].Item -> This will give you current data row

((DataRowView)dgGroup.SelectedCells[0].Item).Row.ItemArray[0] -> This will give first column value
```

Adding some more code based on your comment to loop through sections.

```
            // Find index of selected row which would be group/block row. Add 1 to find first section row in that block/group.
        var index = dgGroup.Items.IndexOf(dgGroup.SelectedItem) + 1;

        // Starting from the index found above loop through section rows untill you find blank row which can be identified by checking if "Group Name" does not have any value.
        for (int i = index; i < dgGroup.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (((DataRowView)dgGroup.Items[i]).Row.ItemArray[1].ToString().Trim() == string.Empty)
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                // Add data to textbox.
            }
        }
```

To improve use experience, you might also look at putting some restriction such that user can select only groups/blocks and not section. If that suits you need.

Comment: Thanks but i tested your anwser :  textBox1.Text=((DataRowView)dgGroup.SelectedItem).Row.ToString gives System.Data.DataRowView but ((DataRowView)dgGroup.SelectedItem).Row.ItemArray[0] works. how can i loop through rows until empty row ? as you see , each block is seprated by one emty row. thanks.

Comment: @ RonakThakkar : Hi, whould you mind helping me ? thanks alot. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19110613/how-to-get-different-index-of-2-row-in-datagrid-in-wpf-c

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to RonakThakkar , i have voted up for his usefull answer.

Because of  Grid SelectionUnit is set to "FullRow" So The First Part of answer to my quesion is :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    if (((DataRowView)dataGrid1.SelectedItem).Row.ItemArray[0].ToString() != string.Empty)
    {
        textBox1.Text=((DataRowView)dataGrid1.SelectedItem).Row.ItemArray[0].ToString()+","+((DataRowView)dataGrid1.SelectedItem).Row.ItemArray[1].ToString()+","+((DataRowView)dataGrid1.SelectedItem).Row.ItemArray[7].ToString();
    }
}
```

and the result in textbox will be : `1,GPA,100`

So the remain part is how can i loop through rows until the empty row that seprate each block?

more explain : for example if the user select the first row , and sectionresultcheckbox and mathcheckbox are checked  , and the button clicked , we should have in text box :
`1,GPA,100` +Next line +`80 , 80, 90 ,70 ,54 ,31`
Thanks for any help.