# how to get different index of 2 row in datagrid in wpf c#?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

i have posted this question below some days ago :

[Trouble using datagrid (or datagridview) in wpf or winform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18529267/trouble-using-datagrid-or-datagridview-in-wpf-or-winform)

now , i have another question  :

i want to get different index of 2 row in datagrid in this way as shown in below but it do not work !

```
     var index = dgGroup.Items.IndexOf(dgGroup.SelectedItem) + 1;

    // Starting from the index found above loop through section rows untill you find blank row which can be identified by checking if "Group Name" does not have any value.

    for (int i = index; i < dgGroup.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        if (((DataRowView)dgGroup.Items[i]).Row.ItemArray[1].ToString().Trim() == string.Empty)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
              int var1 = dgGroup.Items.IndexOf(dgGroup.SelectedItem);
              int var2 = dgGroup.Items.IndexOf(((DataRowView)dgGroup.Items[i]).Row.ItemArray[1].ToString().Trim() == string.Empty);

              if((var2-var1)==2)
             {
                 // Add data to one line data textbox
             }

            else 
            {
                  // Add data to more than one line data textbox
            }

        }
    }
```

what is the problem ?
thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you're trying to do, but I can see a problem with your code.

```
int var1 = dgGroup.Items.IndexOf(dgGroup.SelectedItem);
```

This previous line will get the index of the selected row, but the following line is wrong:

```
int var2 = dgGroup.Items.IndexOf(((DataRowView)dgGroup.Items[i]).Row.ItemArray[1].
ToString().Trim() == string.Empty);
```

I don't see how that can even compile... you are trying to use the following code as the input parameter of the `IndexOf` method, which should take an item from the collection and not a `bool` value:

```
((DataRowView)dgGroup.Items[i]).Row.ItemArray[1].ToString().Trim() == string.Empty
```

I think that you need to replace that line with this instead:

```
int var2 = dgGroup.Items.IndexOf(((DataRowView)dgGroup.Items[i]).Row);
```

Also, shouldn't these bits of code be in the `if` statement instead of the `else`? You said you want to find the item with the blank group name, but in your `if` statement, you just return when you find the blank entry.